# Javascript for loop reversing array

Tags: javascript, telerik

I am populating 2 dropdown controls in a for loop, both controls are telerik dropdowns containing the same data (either months or quarters). Strangely the result of this code is that one control is ordered from Jan-Dec, but the other is reversed, Dec-Jan (the monthToDropdown). I have fixed the issue with the second block of code, but would like to understand WHY this is happening, some sort of reference issue?

Here is the code that produces the alternating dropdowns:

```
 function PeriodChoiceIndexChange(sender, args) {

    var itemText = args.get_item()._text;

    var monthToDropDown,  monthFromDropDown ;

    monthToDropDown = $find("<%= ToMonthDropDown.ClientID %>");
    monthFromDropDown = $find("<%= FromMonthDropDown.ClientID %>");

    var months = new Array();
    months[0] = "Jan";
    months[1] = "Feb";
    months[2] = "Mar";
    months[3] = "Apr";
    months[4] = "May";
    months[5] = "Jun";
    months[6] = "Jul";
    months[7] = "Aug";
    months[8] = "Sep";
    months[9] = "Oct";
    months[10] = "Nov";
    months[11] = "Dec";

    var quarters = new Array();
    quarters[0] = "Q1";
    quarters[1] = "Q2";
    quarters[2] = "Q3";
    quarters[3] = "Q4";

    monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
    monthToDropDown.clearItems();
    monthToDropDown.commitChanges();
    monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
    monthFromDropDown.clearItems();
    monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();

    if (itemText == "Quarterly") {
        for (var i = 0; i < quarters.length; i++) {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(quarters[i]);
            comboItem.set_value(quarters[i]);
            monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthToDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
            monthToDropDown.commitChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
            monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(months[i]);
            comboItem.set_value(months[i]);
            monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthToDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
            monthToDropDown.commitChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
            monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is the code that populates both controls in the same order:

```
    if (itemText == "Quarterly") {
        for (var i = 0; i < quarters.length; i++) {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(quarters[i]);
            comboItem.set_value(quarters[i]);
            var comboItem1 = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem1.set_text(quarters[i]);
            comboItem1.set_value(quarters[i]);
            monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthToDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
            monthToDropDown.commitChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem1);
            monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(months[i]);
            comboItem.set_value(months[i]);
            var comboItem1 = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem1.set_text(months[i]);
            comboItem1.set_value(months[i]);
            monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthToDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
            monthToDropDown.commitChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
            monthFromDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem1);
            monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();
        }
    }
```

So as you see while I have solved the problem, I would like to understand the theory behind this reversal

Comment: Is it `monthToDropDown`  that gets reversed? As an aside, `var quarters = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]` and similar for `months` is shorter and easier than adding one element at a time...

Comment: @nnnnnn edited question thanks, it was monthToDropDown, true about array initiation!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Telerik, but in a general sense when you append an html element to another the element being appended is removed from its previous parent (not copied). So I _guessed_ (obviously I could be completely wrong) that `monthToDropDown` was the reversed one because in your original code when you use `.add(comboItem)` to add the same item to both combos perhaps the second `.add()` removes it from `monthToDropDown` so on each iteration `monthToDropDown` only has one option element - which then confuses the UI component into adding the new one at the beginning of the list.

Comment: (P.S. I was assuming the UI component only uses `monthToDropDown` behind the scenes as a source, and builds a fancier control for display.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @nnnnnn said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325847/javascript-for-loop-reversing-array/24870879#comment30336047_20325847) was correct.  In the loop, we add the element to the first drop down and then attempt to add it to the second.  However, adding the same element to the second drop down will remove it from the first.

I created a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to illustrate what actually happens.

```
function PeriodChoiceIndexChange(sender, args) {
    var monthToDropDown = $find("ToMonthDropDown"),
        monthFromDropDown = $find("FromMonthDropDown");

    var months = new Array();
    months[0] = "Jan";
    months[1] = "Feb";

    monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
    monthFromDropDown.clearItems();
    monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();

    monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
    monthToDropDown.clearItems();
    monthToDropDown.commitChanges();

    for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
        comboItem.set_text(months[i]);
        comboItem.set_value(months[i]);

        alert("[" + i + "][0] From Count = " + monthFromDropDown.get_items().get_count() + "; To Count = " + monthToDropDown.get_items().get_count());

        monthFromDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
        alert("[" + i + "][1] From Count = " + monthFromDropDown.get_items().get_count() + "; To Count = " + monthToDropDown.get_items().get_count());

        monthToDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
        alert("[" + i + "][2] From Count = " + monthFromDropDown.get_items().get_count() + "; To Count = " + monthToDropDown.get_items().get_count());
    }

    alert("[PeriodChoiceIndexChange] End");

    return false;
}
```

When you run this, you will get the following output:

```
Loop  Alert0  Alert1  Alert2
0     0, 0    1, 0    0, 1
1     0, 1    1, 1    0, 2
```

To fix your current method, just change the last block to re-instantiate the item like the following:

```
var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
comboItem.set_text(quarters[i]);
comboItem.set_value(quarters[i]);
monthToDropDown.trackChanges();
monthToDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
monthToDropDown.commitChanges();

comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
comboItem.set_text(quarters[i]);
comboItem.set_value(quarters[i]);
monthFromDropDown.trackChanges();
monthFromDropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
monthFromDropDown.commitChanges();
```